# Why not specialize function templates? (Q&A)

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, overloading, template-specialization

I will try to organize this problem alas Q&A and hope that there will be colleagues who will take something from this.

First, lets answer at first glance a simple question, what is the output of this program?

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void f(T) { std::cout << 1; }

template<>
void f<>(int*) { std::cout << 2; }

template<class T>
void f(T*) { std::cout << 3; }

int main() {
    int *p = nullptr; 
    f( p );
}
```

Comment: The bonus question is of course "what does `f(nullptr)` print?"

Comment: @MSalters `nullptr_t` is not `T*`, Best C++!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your answer was 3, congratulations, you are free to skip this Q&A.

**For everybody else:**

I personally thought that the output should be 2, if you got to this point, I guess you too.
Now lets dive a bit deeper.

The name f is overloaded by the two function templates `void f(T)` and `void f(T*)`. Note that overload resolution only considers the function templates, not the explicit specialisation `void f<>(int*)`! For overload resolution, first we deduce the template arguments for each function template, and get `T = int *` for the first one, and `T = int` for the second.

Both function templates are viable, but which one is best? According to [[over.match.best]§16.3.3¶1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best#1), a function template is a better match than another function template if it's more specialised:

> a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another
> viable function F2 if (...) the function template for F1 is more
> specialized than the template for F2 according to the partial ordering
> rules described in 17.5.6.2

The process of partial ordering is a bit long to quote here, and not key to this question. But in summary, anything accepted by `f(T*)` would also be accepted by `f(T)`, but not the other way around. So `f(T*)` is more specialised.

Now we know that the function template `void f(T*)` is selected by overload resolution, and we can start thinking about specialisations. Which of the function templates is `void f<>(int*)` a specialisation of? [[temp.expl.spec]§17.7.3¶3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#3):

> A declaration of a function template (...) being explicitly
> specialized shall precede the declaration of the explicit
> specialization.

So the explicit specialisation void `f<>(int*)` is a specialisation of `void f(T)`, since that's the only function template declaration that precedes it. Overload resolution however selected the other function template, `void f(T*)`, and we instead call an implicitly instantiated a specialisation of that, printing 3.

For more, please refer to Herb Sutter's [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)